# (Flutter) Customize Dots Indicator and Animation in PageView

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

Customize Dots indicator like this
[image]

I want to be able to customize dots as shown, and give a little animation

Answer (score 6):

You can use [**`smooth_page_indicator`**](https://pub.dev/packages/smooth_page_indicator?fbclid=IwAR3JJru4GJhNucemDrMdp46_viNtT50UuQ27BHgAoy4EgPv1KFRCog0LM7U)

How to use

> First, add `smooth_page_indicator` package in your  `pubspec.yaml` file:
>
> Now install `smooth_page_indicator` package
>
> now use `import 'package:smooth_page_indicator/smooth_page_indicator.dart';`  in your dart file

You can find a complete example here  [smooth_page_indicator](https://github.com/Milad-Akarie/smooth_page_indicator)

Comment: This is freaking awsome !!!!!!!!!
I've spent 3 nights doing the animation of the first dots freaking out how many more I need for my app... Thanks Man!!!